# Rendering nested form error message to different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have tickets and I have replies.  Tickets have many replies, replies belongs to tickets.
At top of my ticket/show page I have a Ticket form that updates a few Ticket parameters.  Starts out with

```
= form_for @ticket do |f|
```

and then closes itself.  This form works fine.

On the same page I have a "Replies form" created with

```
= form_for [@ticket, @ticket.replies.build] do |f|
```

and then closes itself.
Problem is if any of the active record validations are called on the replies form rails redirects to the replies controller with the error messages, but I need it to redirect to the current page I'm on.  I cannot figure this out for the life of me.  Googled around, tried repointing the render in the replies controller to no avail.

Any help is welcomed.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe doing that remotely would solve your problem and bring some userfriendlyness.

If not an option for you, bare in mind that you should do `@reply || @ticket.replies.build` in your form, or else it wont show in the form if there are erros.

Render wont work since it's a different controller so you have 2 options.

1. Create a new action on your ticket controller for creating replies and specify it in your form
2. Use `redirect_to ticket_url(@ticket, @reply)` on your action, and create the route for that, it needs a :ticket_id and :reply_id